# jquery post always return false

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i use this function for a tag click this work fine and my code return true but data variable is false .why??

```
  $('#AddProvince').click(function () {
                var url = '@Url.Action("SetProvinceList")';
                var id = $('#Province').val();
                var result=false;
                $.post(url, { PID: id }, function (data) {
                    if (data == true) {
                        var p = "<tr class='tRow'> <td class='tbody'>" + $('#Province         option:selected').text() + "</td></tr>";
                        $('#tblPRovince tr:last').after(p);
                    }
                });               
            });
```

Comment: open cosole and paste the data valud via `console.log(data)`

Comment: you have taken the var result = false; but did't use any where in the above code.

Comment: 1. make sure that the url value is right. mostly this is the problem. you can do it by printing
2. checking response is by checking response code and not data.

Comment: i check all of them in debug mode it call my function and my function  return true then in debug mode data is false.i dont know why?maybe post is async and callback is not finish yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because data is a String, and not a boolean, just use

```
data == 'true'
```

Answer (score 1):

response from call is always a string, you can try:

```
if(data)
```

or

```
if(data === 'true')
```